# Message error by read timeout keeps appearing even though I add 'try except'

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import schedule
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.call("my_code.py", shell=True)
except:
    pass

def trigger():
    try:
        subprocess.call("my_code.py", shell=True)
    except:
        pass
schedule.every(30).seconds.do(trigger)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)
```

Inside `my_code.py` there is a:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5).json()
```

So that there was no risk of kill the terminal or showing an error message, I added `try except`, thinking that this is how would not show errors and would continue looping the next calls.

But this message (along with several other lines with things written) appears:

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXXXXXXXXX.com', port=443): 
Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

When it reaches the `5 second` limit, how should I proceed so that it doesn't happen since with `try except` it didn't solve the problem?

Detail, I didn't want to add a `try except` together to the `request` in `my_code.py`, I really would like to know if there is any way to protect my run terminal to these errors but just messing with this code I published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information from:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api

You should pass [subprocess.DEVNULL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL) as value for stderr agument:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(
    "my_code.py",
    shell=True,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    )
```

Comment: Hi @RamonMoraes, thank you for being willing to help me. I tried to use it as indicated, but unfortunately this way the subprocess doesn't seem to be triggered, because it is considered finished and waiting for 30 seconds for it to be executed again. I have a ```print("Start")``` at the beginning of the code in ```my_code.py``` to let i know that it started to run, it doesn't even appear.

Comment: @BrondbyIF try passing DEVNULL to stderr argument only.

Comment: Hello friend, good morning (I believe the name is Brazilian too, so it's still morning around here. Lol). Only ```stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL``` solved the issue perfectly, thank you very much!